# Navigation is throwing Twig error when trying to 'preview' a disabled entry

Tags: templating, live-preview

I have an entry that needs to be disabled until the content is finalized. I am not able to 'preview' the entry unless I enable it. If I remove the navigation code, 'preview' will work on the disabled entry. Any ideas on why this is happening?
The Twig Error I am getting is Impossible to access an attribute("registerLink") on a null variable.

[image: Twig Error Image]

Here is our navigation code:

```
{% extends '_layouts/main' %}

{% block main %}

{% set mainEntry = craft.entries.slug(craft.app.request.getSegment(1)).one() %}
{% set academyLink = craft.entries.descendantOf(mainEntry).slug('academy').one() %}
{% set navLink = craft.entries.descendantOf(mainEntry).mainLevelNavigation('1').all() %}
{% set registerLink = mainEntry.registerLink %}
{% set subnav = craft.entries.descendantOf(mainEntry).secondLevelNavigation('1').all() %}
{% set subnav2 = craft.entries.descendantOf(academyLink).level(3).all() %}

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg main-menu">
    <div class="standard-wrapper">
        <div class="navbar-brand logo logo-white visible"><a href="#"><img src="{{siteUrl}}images/logos/UUGC_2019_year-logo_W.png"/></a></div>
        <!--<div class="navbar-brand logo logo-black hidden"><a href="#"><img src="{{siteUrl}}images/logos/unite-generic-black-1.png"/></a></div>-->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse float-right menu" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto no-list-style">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="" href="{{mainEntry.getUrl}}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0);" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Conference
                    </a><i class="dropdown-toggle fa fa-chevron-down" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <ul class="no-list-style">
                            {% for page in subnav %}
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                {{ page.link }}
                            </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                {% if academyLink|length %}
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="{{academyLink.getUrl}}" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{academyLink}}</a><i class="dropdown-toggle fa fa-chevron-down" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <ul class="no-list-style">
                            {% for page in subnav2 %}
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                {{ page.link }}
                            </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
                {% for page in navLink %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        {{ page.link }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                {% if registerLink|length %}
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{registerLink}}">REGISTER</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

{% include "conferences/_types/" ~ entry.type %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a conditional to remove navigation if mainEntry is disabled.

```
{% extends '_layouts/main' %}

{% block main %}

{% set mainEntry = craft.entries.slug(craft.app.request.getSegment(1)).one() %}

{% if mainEntry %}  
{% set academyLink = craft.entries.descendantOf(mainEntry).slug('academy').one() %}
{% set navLink = craft.entries.descendantOf(mainEntry).mainLevelNavigation('1').all() %}
{% set registerLink = mainEntry.registerLink %}
{% set subnav = craft.entries.descendantOf(mainEntry).secondLevelNavigation('1').all() %}
{% set subnav2 = craft.entries.descendantOf(academyLink).level(3).all() %}


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg main-menu">
    <div class="standard-wrapper">
        <div class="navbar-brand logo logo-white visible"><a href="https://conference.ungerboeck.com"><img src="{{siteUrl}}images/logos/UUGC_2019_year-logo_W.png"/></a></div>
        <!--<div class="navbar-brand logo logo-black hidden"><a href="https://conference.ungerboeck.com"><img src="{{siteUrl}}images/logos/unite-generic-black-1.png"/></a></div>-->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse float-right menu" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto no-list-style">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="" href="{{mainEntry.getUrl()}}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0);" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Conference
                    </a><i class="dropdown-toggle fa fa-chevron-down" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <ul class="no-list-style">
                            {% for page in subnav %}
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                {{ page.link }}
                            </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                {% if academyLink|length %}
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="{{academyLink.getUrl}}" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{academyLink}}</a><i class="dropdown-toggle fa fa-chevron-down" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <ul class="no-list-style">
                            {% for page in subnav2 %}
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                {{ page.link }}
                            </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
                {% for page in navLink %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        {{ page.link }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                {% if registerLink|length %}
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{registerLink}}">REGISTER</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

{% endif %}

{% include "conferences/_types/" ~ entry.type %}

{% endblock %}
```